# Which of my email addresses can mods see?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, privacy, email-addresses

I can have email address(es) on my Stack Exchange account for logging in with, and I can have email address(es) for receiving emails about Stack Exchange. I understand that moderators can see user email addresses if they want, but I am unsure about this: **can moderators view email addresses for both logging in and receiving email, or can they only see email addresses for one of the two?**

Answer (score 11):

**Both**.

I can see your login information at `/users/mylogins/<id>`, like you can. That's the email you use for logging in. (Testing with my soockpuppet, though, reveals that I can't actually reset your password. Which is a good thing.)

I can also see what email stuff gets sent to you at, such as mod messages - if I go to send you a mod message, it'll tell me where it sends it to. I can*not* access your other email settings, such as where you set what types of emails you'll get sent from SE.

(All testing was done with my own sockpuppet, so no users' PII besides my own account's was accessed.)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it's the latter. Without delving too deep, logins are handled by a different system.

Your login is stored as a *credential*, and from what I can see, I can't actually see the email behind it, only that you set `$login_provider` at some point in your history. I can see your email address though, through the usual profile page mod info.

Historically (and I don't see any significant reason this should be changed) we used OpenIDs, which were *not* nor *needed to be* email addresses, and still use many OAuth providers (where your logins are not and do not need to be email addresses). Showing us the email address that you use to log in seems kinda useless.

Comment: I don’t understand what the first part of your last paragraph is trying to say.

Comment: I didn't poke too hard at anyone's PII to answer this question, and its possible someone who works here could go "Actually...."

Comment: @Stormblessed you can login via OAuth providers (e.g. Google). Technically, it gives SE token, and there is no need to get, actually, your email. But it does, so mods can see your email, if you are login via, for example, your Google account.

Comment: @Suvitruf I have a Stack Exchange account, it's not linked to my gmail.